# Access model name in Django CreateView from template

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm using the generic CRUD views in Django 1.6, e.g.:

```
class KanriCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'generic_form.html'

class KanriUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'generic_form.html'
```

etc.

N.B. These are classes used as a base class which I subclass inside views.py files throughout the project.

In order to keep DRY I'm writing a generic form template for all create/update views.

For update views, I have access to `object` in the template, which is the instance I am updating. I then use `object.__class__.__name__` (via a custom filter) to get the name of the class (so I can have automatically generated custom buttons like "Add User", "Add Role".etc so the forms look less...generic.

Of course, when I'm using my template in `CreateView`, `object` does not exist (as it has not been created), so my custom buttons.etc do not work, and I get a `VariableDoesNotExist` exception.

Does Django provide the **class** somewhere so I can use it in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The name of your first view should be different, e.g. `KanriCreateView`
2. It might help you to get the name of the view class: {{ view.**class**.**name** }}
3. If you have access to the view class (which is provided by default by the `ContextDataMixin`) you can access the `model` attribute of the view class and get the name of the model: `{{ view.model.__name__ }}`

Cheers

Comment: In regards to 1 that was a typo as I wrote the signatures in the post, rest assured that isn't how it's written ;). I've fixed it up.

Otherwise, thanks very much. Will give it a shot.

Comment: I believe this is no more available in Django 3>
TemplateSyntaxError
Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores: 'view.model.__name__'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a ModelForm for your CreateView, this doesn't quite work.  This is because you're not specifying

```
model = MyModel
```

but instead you're specifying

```
form_class = MyModelForm
```

so what you can do instead is

```
from django.contrib.admin.utils import model_ngettext

model_ngettext(self.form_class._meta.model, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution updated for Django 2 and 3: retrieve the model verbose name from the ModelForm associated to the CreateView.

```
class YourCreateView(CreateView):

    form_class = YourModelForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Add the models verbose name to the context dictionary."""

        kwargs.update({
            "verbose_name": self.form_class._meta.model._meta.verbose_name,})
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Now you can use `{{ verbose_name }}` inside your template.

Please, remark the *double* `_meta` in the code snippet above: the first is meant to access the model from the ModelForm, while the second accesses the verbose name of the Model.

As with internationalization, remark that if your model uses ugettext as shown below, then the verbose name will automatically be translated in the template.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("your verbose name")
```